# Unity5 TextAsset not functioning in WebPlayer

Tags: c#, unity, serialization

## Preface

I am working on a 2D Platformer in Unity5 utilizing TileMap techniques.  I have a working system to read "Room Tile Data" from `JSON` files with the Unity `TextAsset` Class and the Newtonsoft JSON.Net library.  My level files are within a folder inside of the Resources Directory and the `Resources.Load` is working on the json files with and without their `.json` file extension.

[image]

## Code

```
FileName = "MapFiles/room_three";       
TextAsset mapDataFile = Resources.Load(FileName) as TextAsset;
string text = mapDataFile.text;
Map thisLevel = new Map();
thisLevel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Map>(text);
```

## Problem

This works in the standalone builds for win + mac as well as in the Unity Editor.  But a unity Web player Build entirely fails to load the TextAsset and my characters are left falling endlessly.

[image: Falling]

The only error I receive is a reference to `mapDataFile.text` being null.  Leading me to believe my `TextAsset` is failing to load from the web player.  The documentation says nothing I could find about using the `TextAsset` differently in the web player.  Is there a different technique I must use to solve this issue for the Web Player?  I'm certain I could change things to grab files on the web using `WWW`, but I want this data to be loaded from within the application.

## Thanks in advance!

---

## (edit) Updates:

- Created a public property for the `TextAsset` and drag dropped the file into it. Still fails to load from the web player and worked in the standalones + editor. Assuming this means we can rule out `Resources.Load` as our culprit.
- Tried the same functionality with `Resources.LoadAssetAtPath` which was only intended for use in the editor.  When running this in the web player I received a similar verbose message.  Nothing like this appears with `Resources.Load`
- Updated "sample code" containing `FilePath` variable with file path string  value being used in my application
- Tested web player in FireFox / Chrome / Safari on Mac OSX 10.8 Yosemite
- Pursued a potential cause found here: [LINK TO ARTICLE](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/4-game-programming/topics/206727-unity-resources-load-issue-assets-missing-in-webplayer) I copied this technique implementing a scene 0 menu and the problem persisted with a weird flickering in Scene 0
- Deleted Project "Library", "Temp" & "Project Settings" directories and let them be regenerated in conjunction with a few of these other attempts for good measure.  Also removed / regenerated user preferences
- Ran a "Reimport All" Assets by unity, Unsuccessful.
- For posterity, I tried "Turning it Off and On Again" (Rebooting my Machine)
- Uninstalled and Reinstalled newest Unity WebPlayer, unsuccessful.

Comment: FileName = "Folder/Within/Resources/level_one";    ....   try FileName = "Resources/Folder/Within/level_one";

Comment: then try without Resources bit

Comment: Are you building a streaming web player, specifically? And if so, have you set the "First Streamed Level" in player settings? Levels with an index below that setting will not have access to `Resources.Load`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the situation, but it works regardless of what I do. Try to create a new playground project and repeat your situation, but stripped of irrelevant code and content.

P.S.: This should be a comment instead of an answer, but I don't have enough reputation here yet.

Comment: giving this a shot now